# Loop through all urls of the links posted in a post (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a loop that gets the content of a post from a custom post type. The content of this specific post has some links to external images that I want to show in a lightbox - of course one after another:

`

```
    $args = array(
        post_type => 'xyz',
        'p' => 128

    );

    $custom_loop = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) : $custom_loop->the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php * what do I have to enter here * ?>">
    <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
    <img src="def">
    </a>
     <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part('template_parts/content','error');?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`
```

The problem is: How can I loop through all the urls of all the links provided in the post? I only know this: wp_get_attachment_url();

But I don't want the url of an attached image, I only want the urls of the links that are listed in the post. In the frontend, the images provided by these links should be displayed in a lightbox after one clicks on the link which consists of the title of the post (h2) and a thumbnail (img). That's the plan :-)

Maybe I need a loop inside that loop that loops only through the links in the post? You see, I'm completely lost :-D Thx for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will all the links be already in an image tag? If they will be already in an image tag you do not need to go through the links and regenerate the lightbox. You could perform some jquery and enable lightbox on these images.  If the links will not be in an image tag I think you can do something as below:

```
$args = array(
    post_type => 'xyz',
    'p' => 128

);

//We define the regular expression we will be using to fetch all links from the content;
$pattern = '/<a\s+(?:[^"\'>]+|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*href="([^"]+)"|\'[^\']+\'|[^<>\s]+/i';

//Start the WP_Query
$custom_loop = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ){
    while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ){
        $custom_loop->the_post();

        //Perform the regular expression match to get all links from post content
        preg_match_all( $pattern, get_the_content(), $matches );

        //all matches found will be stored in $matches[1]
        if(isset($matches[1]){

            //We make sure to clear all empty values
            $links = array_filter( $matches[1] );

            //Loop through all the links
            foreach ( $links as $link ) {

                //We make sure its a valid url - here we might have '#' since '<a href="#"></a>' will still be fetched by regular expression
                if ( filter_var( $link, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) ) {

                    //If links you will be fetching might not be an image link you have to also add a conditional check to make sure the url is an image source

                    //Generate your links for lightbox

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Omar Tani: Unfortunaltely, I was not able to make this code work for me. Therefore, I have used a meta box for each url which is then called in the code using the following code:

```
<?php $... = get_post_custom( $post->ID ); ?>

<a href="<?php echo $...["image1"][0]; ?>">
```

etc.

Thx anyway for your help!

Comment: Sorry i just saw this, since you did not commwnt on my answer i did nit get notified of your communication. Hope you managed to sort it out.